# How to fill empty array when using Parallel Gem in_processes?

Tags: ruby, arrays, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm running multiple processes, using the Parallel Gem, who use the same array. I initialise my array like `@array ||= Array.new`. However, each process sees this array as not existing and I end up with an empty array.
How can I make all processes fill the same array?

Comment: Could you show us some more code? it would be helpful.

Comment: Processes don't share memory.

Comment: Ok, seems processes aren't going to work. Ty